# Is a.b always (&a)->b?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

In C, `a.b` is normally synonymous with `(&a)->b`.

Is this true in absolutely all cases, even if `a` is a macro for some messy compound term? Or are there any edge cases, in any version of C, in which the equivalence fails to hold?

Comment: Likely you intended to ask about `(a).b` and `(&(a))->b`. Otherwise, `a` could easily be an expression/macro such that precedence interferes with the operators.

Comment: The equivalence is rather this: the notation `p->m` is a shorthand for `(*p).m`.  There is no `&` involved in the fundamental equivalence; that's something you can derive from it, at the loss of generality: the derived equivalence with `&` doesn't hold in situations where `&` is inadmissible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are three counterexamples, all based on constraints on applying `&`:

- `a` is an rvalue because it is a structure returned by a function:

  ```
  int bar(void)
  {
      extern struct S { int b; } foo(void);
      return (&foo())->b;
  }
  ```

  Clang says “error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'struct S'”. But it accepts `return foo().b;`.
- `a` is an rvalue because it is the result of an assignment:

  ```
    int bar(void)
    {
        struct S { int b; } x = {0};
        struct S y;
        return (&(y=x))->b;
    }
  ```

  Clang says “error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'struct S'”. But it accepts `return (y=x).b;`.
- `a` is declared with `register`, so its address may not be taken:

  ```
  int bar(void)
  {
      register struct S { int b; } a = {0};
      return (&a)->b;
  }
  ```

  Clang says “error: address of register variable requested”.

Answer (score 11):

In `a.b`, `a` is not required to be an lvalue.

For example, if `a` is a macro that expands to a function call, then `(&a)->b` is a constraint violation.

Answer (score 3):

> In C, `a.b` is normally synonymous with `(&a)->b`.

There is nothing in the `C11` standard that *mandates* this equivalence under all circumstances. The relevant section (`5.5.2.3 Structure and union members`) actually deals with them distinctly and the footnote in that section indicates where the misapprehension arises:

> If `&E` is a valid pointer expression (where `&` is the "address-of" operator, which generates a pointer to its operand), the expression `(&E)->MOS` is the same as `E.MOS`.

In other words, `&E` has to be valid for this equivalence to hold. One place where it *doesn't* hold is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct xyzzy { int plugh; } twisty;
struct xyzzy getTwistyCopy(void) { return twisty; }

int main(void) {
    twisty.plugh = 42;
    printf("%d\n", (   getTwistyCopy()  ).plugh);
    printf("%d\n", ( &(getTwistyCopy()) )->plugh);
}
```

The first `printf` line is fine but the second is not. That's really because you cannot take the address of a function return value. But you can still see, for an arbitrary `a`, that `a.b` and `(&a)->b` are not always identical.